# How to set to 0 notification count android firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-notifications

How to set to 0 notification count android using firebase after opening the app?

Is there any equivalent of swift's `applicationDidBecomeActive`

`UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Removing All Notifications
    cancelAllNotifications();
}

private void cancelAllNotifications() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```